# Hangfire and Unit of Work

Tags: c#, generics, hangfire

I am sure this is mostly my lack of understanding around generics and expressions, but I am trying to create a list of `Expression<Action<T>>` in order to call BackgroundJob.Enqueue once I am in a commit state.

I have several areas of the code that may want to enqueue a job, but they don't know if the job should actually run until another section of the code, specifically a save to the db, occurs.

What I am struggling with is creating a `List<Expression<Action<T>>>` when T is obviously different, and passing it to BackgroundJob.Enqueue when ready.

```
public class HangfireQueue
{
    private readonly IList<Expression<Action<object>>> _queuedItems;

    public HangfireQueue()
    {
        _queuedItems = new List<Expression<Action<object>>>();
    }

    public virtual void EnqueueTask<T>( Expression<Action<T>>  methodCall )
    {
        _queuedItems.Add( methodCall );
    }

    public void CommitUnitOfWork()
    {
        foreach ( var item in _queuedItems )
        {
            BackgroundJob.Enqueue( (Expression<Action>) item );
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a number of different methods, this happens to be the lastest attempt, sometimes I get it to compile and it doesn't like it at run time, unable to cast `Expression<Action<T>>` to `Expression<Action>` would be part of the problems here, not to mention that the methodCall would not be accepted in the list.

Comment: Have you got some sample code outlining the issue you're having?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably `Enqueue` takes an `Expression<Action>` as a parameter - that's an expression which evaluates to a void method which takes **no parameters**.

You are trying to pass `Expression<Action<T>>` instead - evaluating to a void method which takes **one parameter**. The compiler will never allow that.

Use `Expression<Action>` instead:

```
public class HangfireQueue
{
    private readonly IList<Expression<Action>> _queuedItems;

    public HangfireQueue()
    {
        _queuedItems = new List<Expression<Action>>();
    }

    public virtual void EnqueueTask(Expression<Action> methodCall)
    {
        _queuedItems.Add(methodCall);
    }

    public virtual void EnqueueTask<T>(Expression<Action<T>> methodCall, T p1)
    {
        _queuedItems.Add(() => methodCall.Compile()(p1));
    }

    public virtual void EnqueueTask<T1,T2>(Expression<Action<T1,T2>> methodCall, T1 p1, T2 p2)
    {
        _queuedItems.Add(() => methodCall.Compile()(p1, p2));
    }

    public void CommitUnitOfWork()
    {
        foreach (Expression<Action> item in _queuedItems)
        {
            BackgroundJob.Enqueue(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Now to add your methods, using the lambda syntax to create `Expression<Action>` objects which will call the code you want to enqueue:

```
HangfireQueue q = new HangfireQueue();

q.EnqueueTask(AnyMethod, anyParameter);

q.EnqueueTask(() => 
{ 
    AnyMethod(anyParameter); 
    OtherMethod("hello", "world"); 
});

q.CommitUnitOfWork();
```

Comment: Yep, had it working with the Expression<Action> however this doesn't allow for Interface usages, in my case I guess that is okay, since i control the Ioc implementation as well.  I was hoping for `q.EnqueueTask<IDoSomething>( i => i.DoSomething("foo"));'  But as you say it does work.

Comment: Where would the value for *i* come from? Its required to execute the action.

Comment: Ioc within Hangfire client, it resolves the IDoSomething

Comment: so I end up with, using autofac, a `container.RegisterType<DoSomething>().As<IDoSomething>` line and a `container.RegisterType<DoSomething>().AsSelf() in order to accommodate both the straight up usage of DoSomething that Hangfire serializes and the IDoSomething that may be injected into another class.

Comment: You need to pass the injected object in as a parameter. Answer edited - see overloads of EnqueueTask().